# How to make version-sort command work in a sh file?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to use "sort -V" command (aka version-sort) in a sh file.
Specifically, I have the following line of code in a sh file:

```sh
SOME_PATH="$(ls dir_1/dir_2/v*/filename.txt | sort -V | tail -n1)"
```

What I'm trying to accomplish through the above command is that given a list of file paths with different version numbers, I want to get the file path with the greatest version number.
For example, let's assume that I have the following list of file paths:

- `dir_1/dir_2/v1/filename.txt`,
- `dir_1/dir_2/v2/filename.txt`,
- `dir_1/dir_2/v11/filename.txt`

Then, I want the command to return `dir_1/dir_2/v11/filename.txt` instead of `dir_1/dir_2/v2/filename.txt` since the former has the greatest version value, "11".

From my understanding the above linux command precisely accomplishes this.
I confirmed it working on the Linux bash terminal.
However, when I run a sh file with the above command in it, I'm getting a
`"ERROR: Unknown command line flag 'V'"` error message.
Is there a way to make version-sort work in a sh file?
If not, is there a way to implement it not using -V flag?
Thank you.

Comment: Is this failing on the same computer as the working one?

Comment: @Greenhouse : Do a `sort --version` to verify which `sort` you have installed. The error message suggests that you don't run GNU sort. With GNU sort, the error message would be _sort: unknown option -- V_.

Comment: if you use a version of `sort` which can do version-sorting, make sure you sort by the right numbers. Add a location key: `sort -t"/" -k3V`

Comment: `sort` is not part of bash _or_ sh, so which version of sort you have and which shell you execute your script with are completely unrelated to each other. If you don't have `sort -V` in a sh script, you wouldn't have it in a bash script or zsh script or any other script running on the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

Using shell's `printf` and `awk`:

```sh
SOME_PATH=$(printf %s\\0 dir_1/dir_2/v*/filename.txt |
  awk 'BEGIN{FS="/";RS="\0";v=0}{match($3,/v([[:digit:]]+)/,m);if(m[1]>v){v=m[1];l=$0}}END{print l}')
```

Using `awk` only:

```sh
SOME_PATH=$(awk 'BEGIN{delete ARGV[0];v=0;for(i in ARGV){split(ARGV[i],s,"/");match(s[3],/v([[:digit:]]+)/,m);if(m[1]>v){v=m[1];l=ARGV[i]}}}END{print l}' dir_1/dir_2/v*/filename.txt)
```

Formatted `awk` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S awk -f

BEGIN {
  delete ARGV[0]
  v=0
  for (i in ARGV) {
    split(ARGV[i], s, "/")
    match(s[3], /v([[:digit:]]+)/, m)
    if (m[1]>v) {
      v=m[1]
      l=ARGV[i]
    }
  }
}
END {
  print l
}
```

Using a `null` delimited list stream, and not parsing the output of `ls` <sup>*1*</sup>:

```sh
SOME_PATH=$(
  printf '%s\0' dir_1/dir_2/v*/filename.txt |
    sort -z -t'/' -k3V |
    tail -zn1 |
    tr -d '\0'
)
```

How it works:

- `printf '%s\0' dir_1/dir_2/v*/filename.txt`: Expands the paths into a `null` delimited stream output.
- `sort -z -t'/' -k3V`: Sorts the `null` delimited input stream on `-k3V` version number from the 3<sup>rd</sup> column, `-t'/'` using `/` as a delimiter.
- `tail -zn1`: Outputs the least `null` delimited entry from the input stream.
- `tr -d '\0'`: Trim-out any remaining `null` to prevent the shell from complaining with error: `warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input`.

---

1. [StackExchange: Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Comment: ...though if the OP doesn't have `sort -V`, I worry that they won't have `sort -z` either.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Added an `awk` method